# why /var/lib/docker/overlay2 grows too large and restart solved it

Tags: docker

I am running a code optimizer for gzip.c in docker, in this process `overlay` grows infinitely large that eat up my disk.

```
root@id17:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/fe6987bf6e686e771ba7b08cda40aa477979512e182ad30120db037024638aa0# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
/dev/sda5       245G  245G     0 100% /
...
overlay         245G  245G     0 100% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/fe6987bf6e686e771ba7b08cda40aa477979512e182ad30120db037024638aa0/merged
```

By using `du -h --max-depth=1` I find it is `diff` and `merged` that consumed up my disk(*is it?*)

```
root@id17:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/fe6987bf6e686e771ba7b08cda40aa477979512e182ad30120db037024638aa0# du -h --max-depth=1
125G    ./diff
129G    ./merged
8.0K    ./work
254G    .
```

However, when I restart the docker`systemctl restart docker`, it returned to normal.

```
root@eb9bf52aa3a3:/# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay         245G  190G   43G  82% /
...
/dev/sda5       245G  190G   43G  82% /etc/hosts
...
```

```
root@id17:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/fe6987bf6e686e771ba7b08cda40aa477979512e182ad30120db037024638aa0# du -h --max-depth=1
125G    ./diff
129G    ./merged
8.0K    ./work
254G    .
```

It has come out for times and I cannot continue to do my work. So I really wonder how can I get out from this problem. Really thank you:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the docker filesystem is growing, that often indicates container logs, or filesystem changes in the container. Logs you can see with `docker logs` and filesystem changes are shown with `docker diff`. Since you see a large diff folder, it's going to be the latter.

Those filesystem changes will survive a restart of the container, they get cleaned when the container is removed and replaced with a new container. So if restarting the container resolves it, my suspicion is your application is deleting the files on disk, but still has the file handles open to the kernel, possibly still writing to those file handles.

The other option is the stop or start of your application is deleting the files.

Comment: I killed the thread that still working, and it turned out that it returned my swallowed disk place. Though I don't know why the thread is not killed by `timeout -s 9`, at least I know how to fix it. Really thank you ^_^